# About a matrix, its powers, and a particular value...

Tags: matrices, exponentiation

Is it possible to find two matrices, $A$ an $B$ such that:

$$A B^0 x = \begin{pmatrix}
        c_0 \\
        ? \\
        ? \\
        \end{pmatrix},
$$
$$A B^1 x = \begin{pmatrix}
        c_1 \\
        ? \\
        ? \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$A B^2 x = \begin{pmatrix}
        c_2 \\
        ? \\
        ? \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$\dots$$
$$A B^{m-1} x = \begin{pmatrix}
        c_{m-1} \\
        ? \\
        ? \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$(A B^m = A B^1) \text{ or } (A B^m = A B^0)
$$

In other words, we would have two $n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$, and a vector $x$.  We are interested in the topmost coefficient of the results of the above multiplications.  Also, $B$ to a high enough power is equal to $B$.

If we can do this, how would we find $A$ and $B$?

I'm primarily interested in the case where we are working modulo integers, but I'm also interested in the case with reals.  As for the $c_i$s, they are given ahead of time.  The vectors on the right are in $Z^n$.

Comment: Are there any conditions on the $c_i$? Are they given beforehand? or are they up to us to choose? Are the vectors on the right supposed to be in ${\bf R}^3$? Is $x$ supposed to be in ${\bf R}^3$?

Comment: No quantifiers whatsoever.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I've added the domain, and the $c_i$s are given ahead of time.

Comment: Is there any relation between $m$ and $n$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson:  I'm hoping that $m$ and $n$ can be equal, but they don't have to be.

Comment: Is $x$ given? Did you actually think about how you were going to present this question, or did you just write up the first things that came into your head?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: $x$ can be anything.  I'm sorry for the poor presentation.  I did think a little about the question, but not nearly enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An idea would be to choose $B$ such that it rotates the coordinates of $x$.
For this consider $B$ as the matrix with $0$ everywhere except a line of $1$ over the diagonal.
Here I supposed $n=m=4$ but the idea may clearly be generalized :

$\quad B:=\quad$$\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}\quad$ while $\ x:=\quad
 \begin{bmatrix}
c_0\\
c_1\\
c_2\\
c_3\\
\end{bmatrix}$

$A$ is simply the identity.